# Failed to transform file '45907c80e09917e1b776adf038505958' to match attributes {artifactType=jar} using transform AarTransform

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0, android-gradle-3.0

I am using Android 3.0 canary 4 and making an app. Everything was working fine until yesterday, but today when i opened the project, it gave me an error

```
 F:\test projects\SellIT\app\build.gradle
Error:Failed to resolve: Failed to transform file '45907c80e09917e1b776adf038505958' to match attributes {artifactType=jar} using transform AarTransform
<a href="openFile:F:/test projects/SellIT/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Error:Failed to resolve: Failed to transform file '0424053f6b3433893454e7542cca3a9d' to match attributes {artifactType=jar} using transform AarTransform
<a href="openFile:F:/test projects/SellIT/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Error:Failed to resolve: Failed to transform file 'customtabs-25.0.0.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-exploded-aar} using transform ExtractAarTransform
<a href="openFile:F:/test projects/SellIT/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Error:Failed to resolve: Failed to transform file 'recyclerview-v7-25.4.0.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-exploded-aar} using transform ExtractAarTransform
<a href="openFile:F:/test projects/SellIT/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Error:Failed to resolve: Failed to transform file 'b7ae5d97f624a2ac68ed171c25f74f21' to match attributes {artifactType=jar} using transform AarTransform
<a href="openFile:F:/test projects/SellIT/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Error:Failed to resolve: Failed to transform file 'firebase-analytics-impl-10.2.4.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-exploded-aar} using transform ExtractAarTransform
<a href="openFile:F:/test projects/SellIT/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Error:Failed to resolve: Failed to transform file '8a727da2aab64813ae6d20842b03d41f' to match attributes {artifactType=jar} using transform AarTransform
<a href="openFile:F:/test projects/SellIT/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Error:Failed to resolve: Failed to transform file 'support-compat-25.4.0.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-exploded-aar} using transform ExtractAarTransform
<a href="openFile:F:/test projects/SellIT/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Error:Failed to resolve: Failed to transform file 'd0da7bf76907aa33e493551504efa952' to match attributes {artifactType=jar} using transform AarTransform
<a href="openFile:F:/test projects/SellIT/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

this is my `build.gradle` (app level)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.sellit"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.4'

    // Required only if Facebook login support is required
    implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.4'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.4'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.4'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Has anyone encountered a similar error or he knows what can I do?

Comment: thanks for the edit @Panciz

Comment: I had a similar error where it says "Failed to transform file 'uninstalltiontracking.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes} using transform JarTransform"
on switching to android studio 3

Comment: so how did you solve it @PenduDev

Comment: ya! i noticed that the .jar file was actually not present in the libs directory, so I removed the line `implementation...uninstallationtracking.jar` from the modules gralde file.

Comment: Have you tried `Invalidate Cache and Restart`option in the File menu

Comment: @penduDev I have tried it, but still there is the error, and in my case,the project was working fine till the night before and the error is consistent even if I create a new project.

Comment: U can try this brute force way to pinpoint ur error.
1. Create a new empty project. 2. Add the gradle lines one by one and compile after each line is added. 3. You will know which line is causing the problem
. worth trying. Plus. Google libs are least likely to cause the prob, so try the other libs first

Comment: all my dependencies are causing problems, even the default `appcompact and constraint layout dependencies`. I tried removing these and sync the project, but then it gave me other errors in my project.

Comment: you can try a fresh install of android studio

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid it, trying to find a solution of the problem. But i guess, I'll have to reinstall it finally.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It turns out that this is a weird bug in the Gradle itself. I posted it on google forum and one of their coders gave me a solution and also put it up as an issue with the gradle team.

For the solution, you can clear your project cache (`C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1` ) and rebuild your project again and it will work fine. The gradle needs some artifacts to build which are stored in the cache memory. So if the gradle fails to build, the cache can be cleared which will prompt fresh downloading. You can be offline as long as all the artifacts you need have been downloaded in Gradle's cache (so don't delete the cache folder when offline!)

Comment: Anything else you had to do @anuj? Clearing transforms-1 folder seems to not resolve the issue.

Comment: Clearing the cache folder folder worked fine for me. Try clearing the other cache files too present in the caches folder. Don't worry, anything u delete in cache will be downloaded when u open Android studio again. Also make sure you are connected to internet when u start your Android studio.

Comment: i tried all the methods. didn't work for me. clear cache folder, invalidate cache and restart, reinstall android studio. nothing worked for me. help me please

Comment: In my case the error was, the file path of the library folder was too long and that's why it couldn't find file. Moving project to the outermost folder of drive solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Faced the same issue. The simple way to solve this is to switch between your build variants. This refreshes the cached copies and resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to be caused by corrupt Jetified files.

Delete ONLY the corrupted .jars from the error message from the Gradle caches folder:

```
rm ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/path-to/some-release.aar
```

The "path-to" will be probably be the package name e.g., `com.example.somerelease`

Usually I get the path of the file to delete from the error message itself and cut and paste it into the terminal in order to execute the `rm` command.

Deleting the entire folder is not an optimal solution as all the dependencies will need to be Jetified again. If you're already having corruption issues, you're likely to encounter the issue again as there is more work for Jetify when it has to reprocess the entire folder

Answer (score 1):

Received similar error:

> Failed to transform file 'uat-release.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes}
>   Transform output file D:\R\project\uat-release.jar does not exist.

In my case, Actual file was *aar* and bymistake I put *.jar* in build.gradle(of uat-release module)

```
  configurations.maybeCreate("default")
  artifacts.add("default", file('uat-release.jar'))
```

Solved it by correcting file type:

```
  configurations.maybeCreate("default")
  artifacts.add("default", file('uat-release.aar'))
```

Comment: Hi, under build.gradle, in which block do i put this code?

Comment: When u add aar as a module, it creates build.gradle in that module. Put it there.

Comment: That's right, and here is the example: in https://github.com/textileio/notes/commit/8e4f12d7ebbf7a3407affd1c7a7f24a579f19940 , `compile project(':mobile')` in android/app/build.gradle , `configurations.maybeCreate("default")` in android/mobile/build.gradle , `include ':mobile'` in android/settings.gradle

Answer (score 0):

go to destination :
**Android\sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar.**
and delete what inside android-jar and rebuild project and sync
worked for me .