# Android Studio apk build error

Tags: java, android, gradle, build, apk

I am new to Android Studio and android development at all. I want to build an .apk file but the error occurs. As a rookie, I basically don't know what to do and what could cause that type of error.
[Log here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0ObW.jpg)

Comment: Your artifacts aren't imported. Did you run `gradle cJ` before building the project? Does that generate any error?

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin oh.. So how can I import them?

Comment: Make sure your build.gradle file is correctly formatted. Follow this pattern for including all the dependencies https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#dependency-types. Then run `gradle clean build`.

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin I added Local binary dependency line, ran clean build but the error persists.

Comment: Could you clear your local gradle cache? Like stated in this Answer by Anuj https://stackoverflow.com/a/45553123/2453382