# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'lifecycle-viewmodel.aar

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I use latest Android Studio 3.5 version (Android Gradle plugin 3.5.0). When I try to compile I receive this error:

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>   Failed to transform artifact 'lifecycle-viewmodel.aar
>   (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0)' to match attributes
>   {artifactType=jar}. Show Details Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact
>   'lifecycle-viewmodel.aar
>   (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0)' to match attributes
>   {artifactType=jar}. Show Details Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact
>   'lifecycle-viewmodel.aar
>   (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0)' to match attributes
>   {artifactType=jar}. Show Details Affected Modules: app

Comment: Another thing to try if you get a similar error: try a different build variant; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50483096/56285

Comment: got the same problem did you found a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please share your build.gradle file ? Although I am not sure but it may works

Solution 1: Go to "File". Click on Invalidate Cache/ Restart. Again click on Invalidate Cache / Restart

Solution 2: Change

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
to
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

Solution 3:
comment out one by one in dependencies and try to run

Comment: Not Working in my case

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.demo"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: comment out one by one in dependencies and try to run.

Comment: thank it's working  i comment implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0' this dependency

Comment: Welcome. Its my pleasure to help you. Please accept the solution by click accept mark. When the same problem will come everyone can see this solution.

Comment: thanks! big help. Im having this error:

(Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'annotation-experimental.aar) 

I tried to comment out this:
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'

and it works okay now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your library or Copy your library name from refactor and paste it in build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, updating gradle.properties worked.

Before:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
```

After:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M
```